# Azure Function running multiple times - Service Bus Trigger

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am facing some weird issue with Azure function and service bus trigger.

**Setup:** I have 1 service bus queue (with session enabled) which has max. delivery count of 1 as shown below:-

[image]

I have an Azure function which gets triggered by a message in service bus queue. The function is combining multiple excel files into 1. But when I run a large number of files, the function seems to be running multiple times as shown in the logs:-

[image]

Earlier I thought that the message lock is getting released but I have already set the `maxAutoRenewDuration` to 1 hour (The function is using Premium plan). So I tested by simply adding a delay of 12 minutes and it's working as expected:-

[image]

Could you let me know why it's happening? Is the function crashing due to memory or something, if yes, why I am not getting any error message?

Comment: are you using durable function ? could you share some code with us to reproduce ?

Comment: No, it's a normal azure function. The code is simply adding few worksheets into one workbook and as you can see from the screenshot, I am printing filenames.

Comment: Are you completing the message? Do you have AutoComplete set to true?

Comment: @JoshLove - Yes, automcomplete is set to `True`. As I said, when I simply added a Delay for 12 minutes, it's working fine and completing the message. It's just when I am doing some code which is CPU-bound it's not erroring but showing re-starting log again and again.

Comment: Can you share what version of the extension you are using?

Comment: @JoshLove - Version 2.